# How to trap error for empty directory property variable error 8000500D

Tags: error-handling, vbscript

In a script that retrieves user attributes from active directory, there is one attribute that is sometimes empty, but I can't seem to trap the error for when it is empty. IsNull, IsObject, IsEmpty, and IsBlank do not seem to be able to catch it. Every time I run the script, I get the error `the directory property cannot be found in the cache` with the code `8000500D`

Is there a way that I can trap that error?

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnvironment = WshShell.Environment("process")
Set ADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & ADSysInfo.UserName)
```

```
strFax = ""
    'check if fax number exists. Throw warning message if missing
    If IsObject(objUser.FaxNumber) and Not isNull(objUser.FaxNumber)
        If Not IsBlank(objUser.FaxNumber) Then
            strFax = objUser.FaxNumber
        Else
            MsgBox "Please be aware that the fax number is missing", vbExclamation, "Attribute Missing"
        End If
    End If
```

[edit]:
Would this be the best way to trap the error, and also allow other unrelated errors to be thrown normally?

```
On Error Resume Next
    strFax = objUser.FaxNumber
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please be aware that the fax number is missing", vbExclamation, "Attribute Missing"
        Err.clear()
        strFax=""
    End If
on error goto 0
```

Comment: You could move the code in the edit part of your question to an answer,. Once the `On Error Resume Next` is reset using `On Error GoTo 0`, the script will behave as usual, will stop on any error.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be the best way to trap the error, and also allow other unrelated errors to be thrown normally?

```
On Error Resume Next
    strFax = objUser.FaxNumber
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please be aware that the fax number is missing", vbExclamation, "Attribute Missing"
        Err.clear()
        strFax=""
    End If
on error goto 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **Property Cache** as demonstrated in the code below, the idea is:

1. Clear the property cache (`objUser.PurgePropertyList`).
2. Retrieve the attribute (`objUser.GetInfoEx Array("FaxNumber"), 0`), this should populate the property cache with the value of the attribute if it has been set.
3. Check the property count in the property cache (`If objUser.PropertyCount < 1 Then`), if it is less than one, then the value of the attribute is not set, otherwise, retrieve the value of the attribute (`strFax = objUser.FaxNumber`).

See also:

[IADsPropertyList::PurgePropertyList method (iads.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadspropertylist-purgepropertylist)

[Error code 0x8000500D when trying to access PasswordLastChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809028/error-code-0x8000500d-when-trying-to-access-passwordlastchanged), somewhat a similar question.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnvironment = WshShell.Environment("process")
Set ADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & ADSysInfo.UserName)

strFax=""
objUser.PurgePropertyList
objUser.GetInfoEx Array("FaxNumber"), 0

If objUser.PropertyCount < 1 Then
 MsgBox "Please be aware that the fax number is missing", vbExclamation, "Attribute Missing"
Else
 strFax = objUser.FaxNumber
End If
```